# Error in Wamp server shows Error: C:/wamp or PHP in PATH

Tags: php, laravel, server, wamp

**1. when i click on error i get this**

> Sorry, There is an error. It seems that a PHP installation is declared
>   in the environment variable PATH C:\php
>
> There is Wampserver path (c:/wamp) into Windows PATH environnement
>   variable: (C:\wamp\bin\php)
>
> Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment
>   variable. Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version is detrimental to
>   the proper functioning of Wampserver.
>
> Press ENTER to continue...

2. **then i check my enviroment variable [see here screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoEsc.png)**
3. **i am working in php framework laravel when i type php artisan migrate it show error**

> [PDOException]   could not find driver

4. **then check my phpinfo then search pdo see this [screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngSkg.png)**

Answer (score 0):

while wamp installation you need to set path of wamp to directory where "php.exe" file is exist.. then it will be solved

Comment: this is my wamp directory path C:\wamp sir will you eleborate more

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a reference to `C:\php` in the Systems Variables path (check your environment variables), and it is confusing WAMP.
When you run the migration, you are probably using the `php` interpreter that is in `C:\php` that doesn't have PDO mysql driver.

I would suggest to try to remove the reference to `C:\php` in the Path variable.

Comment: sir in enviroment variable this path included C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.35.               r u saying   use like this  C:\wamp\bin/

Comment: No, in your first screenshot you are showing the value of path for your user: it says `User variables for ajaya`. Under that box there is a another list of environment variables, called `System variables`. In there there is another `Path` variable that (among other things) contains C:\php in its value. From there try to remove C:\php, if you have permissions to do it.

Comment: i removed sir but problem still happening

Comment: Did you restart your system? All involved long running processes need a restart to pick up the new configuration.

Comment: i restart my pc 4 times problem still occur

Answer (score -1):

- Do you try with the php 7.0 becuase maybe your laravel version doesn't support by wamp server.
- Please check that first and let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: mr joshi i change my php version to 7.0.29 same problem again

Comment: [PDOException] could not find driver

Comment: I hope this link works for and if not than again let me know 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-migrate-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: Okay let me find out other stuff that helps you.